# World plugin tutorial, models not in the EntityTree

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Following the World Plugin tutorial http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_world I noticed something strange.

After spawning the different models, they are not yet taken into account by the plugin.
For instance if you try World::PrintEntityTree(), it won't show the spawned models.

Is there a way to acces spawned model in the world plugin?

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21088/world-plugin-tutorial,-models-not-in-the-entitytree/) by [kincurt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7267/kincurt/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kincurt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7267/kincurt/) on 2018-11-16**:
That is particularly useful to insert identical models without name conflicts (changing the name right after spawn) because gazebo won't allow to spawn two time in a row an identical model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

i did something similar and recognized that i takes some time until the model is inserted correctly.
Assuming you use

```
world_->InsertModelSDF(modelSDF);
```

you could wait a bit

```
common::Time::MSleep(500); // sleep half a second
```

before printing out all models. Also make sure the simulation is running and not paused.
To access all models you can do something like:

```
for(std::vector<T>::iterator mod = world_->GetModels.begin(); mod != GetModels.end(); ++mod){
     printf("Model Name: %s",mod->GetName());
}
```

Two Edits to my Answer. They are probably not necessary! But i add them if someone runs in similar problems and the things above are not working:

MSleep(500) cause the thread to sleep, this may be problematic (or maybe not, depends :P). If its not working try to use:

```
  world_->Step(500);
```

instead.

In the for loop maybe use:

```
std::vector<physics::Model>::iterator mod = ......
```

and not the generic type.

---

Originally posted by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) with karma: 350 on 2018-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kincurt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7267/kincurt/) on 2018-11-20**:
Thanks ! :)

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-11-21**:
Your Welcome :) I edited my answer, if it is already working for you, you can ignore it.